# php quiz undefined offset error

Tags: php

```
 <?php
    $connection=mysql_connect('localhost','root',"");
    if(!$connection)
    {
        die("database connection failed".mysql_error());
    }
    $db_select=mysql_select_db("db",$connection);
    if(!$db_select)
    {
        die("database connection failed".mysql_error());
    }
    if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        echo "<form method=\"post\" action=\"test1.php\">";
        $sub_result=mysql_query("SELECT * from test where tid='1' order by rand() limit 0,2",$connection);
        if(!$sub_result)
        {
            die("database query failed". mysql_error());
        }

        while ($sub_row=mysql_fetch_array($sub_result))
        {
            $id=$sub_row["qno"];
            $ques=$sub_row["ques"];
            $opt1=$sub_row["opt1"];
            $opt2=$sub_row["opt2"];
            $opt3=$sub_row["opt3"];
            $opt4=$sub_row["opt4"];
            $ans=$sub_row["ans"];

            echo "<h3>Q".$id." :".$ques."</br></h3>";   
            echo"</br>
                $opt1
                <input type= radio name=\"{$id}\" value=\"{$opt1}\" >
                </br>
                $opt2
                <input type= radio name=\"{$id}\" value=\"{$opt2}\">
                </br>
                $opt3
                <input type= radio name=\"{$id}\" value=\"{$opt3}\">
                </br>
                $opt4
                <input type= radio name=\"{$id}\" value=\"{$opt4}\">
                </br></br>";
        }
        echo"<input type='submit' value='see how you did it' name='submit'>";
        echo"</form>";

    }


        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {

        $total=0;
        $answer=mysql_query("select qno,ans from test",$connection);

        while($ans=mysql_fetch_assoc($answer))
        {
            if($_POST[$ans['qno']] === $ans['ans'])
            {
                $total++;
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }
        echo"<p align=center><b>I Got $total</b>";
        }
 ?>
```

**Error coming "UNDEFINED OFFSET in line 60, where I am validating the answer."**

Comment: Please highlight the line throwing the error, with a comment.

Comment: He did, it's line 60: `if($_POST[$ans['qno']] === $ans['ans'])`.

Comment: you're apparently grabbing ALL questions in your database and checking if there's an answer for it in the posted results. .... why? let's say you've got 500 questions, but the quiz has only 10 on it. you're doing at least 490 **USELESS** operations...

Comment: @MarcB but how can I check that which were the random questions picked ? I can add a where clause to check its tid though.

Comment: loop on the submitted answers. that should contain the IDs of the questions you used. use those IDs to fetch only the relevant answers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the variable # set in `$ans['qno']` does not exist as a pair in array `$_POST` (`$_POST` has fewer array values than the # set in `$ans['qno']`)

Change line 60 from:

`if($_POST[$ans['qno']] === $ans['ans']) {`

to:

`if( isset( $_POST[$ans['qno']] ) && ( $_POST[ $ans['qno'] ] === $ans['ans'] ) ) {`

We are using `isset()` to first make sure `$_POST[x]` exists, and only if it does, compare it to `$ans['ans']`.